# PHP JavaScript redirect issue

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<script>";
echo "  function logout()";
echo "  {";
echo "  var r=confirm(\"Are you sure you want to logout?\");";
echo "  if (r==true){window.location.href=\"http://www.google.com\";}";
echo "  }";
echo "</script>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<div ALIGN=\"right\" onclick=\"logout();\"> <a href=\"\">Logout </a> </div>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

From the above code, I just want to redirect the user to `www.google.com` once the user click "YES" in the confirm box. I tried to alert right after (`r == true`), it works, however the page doesn't go to `www.google.com`. May I know what I've missed out?

Comment: Why not use PHP templating? `?><script>//real javascript</script><?php`

Comment: As I've said, I able to alert some text, meaning the way I code it should've no problem with it. I don't want to make too many unnecessary code changes onto current code as the code above is just a  small portion of the real code

Comment: With handlebar template can you doing it, I thing ...

Comment: @josecarlos: I'm totally lost now. What you mean by using handlebar template. I'm just trying to redirect the user to some other pages which should be very easy, I thought?

Comment: @IsaacLem: Can't imagine the rest of the code... Doesn it look much nicer like this https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/6504365? Dunno... if I see that in production I would go crazy!

Comment: Yeap I will try to refine the code after all the necessary functions been done. Thanks for your input.

Comment: In any case, I think your code should work, have you tried isolating it and trying the JavaScript alone?

Comment: @IsaacLem: With handlebar template your code will be simple and can create condition, loop, so on. Please read the follow: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,I think you should add same code like this: 
`echo "<div ALIGN=\"right\" onclick=\"logout();\"><a      href=\"javascript:return;\">Logout </a> </div>";`
because the page has refreshed after the click event bind on DIV element triggered.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have Jquery and Jquery UI

```
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<script>";
    echo '$( "#dialog-logout" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        resizable: false,
        height:160,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Logout": function() {
            location.href = "http://www.google.com";
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );},
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );}}});
        $( "#logout" )
        .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-logout" ).dialog( "open" );});'

    echo "</script>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";


    echo "<div ALIGN=\"right\" id=\"logout\"> <a href=\"\">Logout </a> </div>";
    echo '<div id="dialog-logout" title="Logout">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>You are about to logout. Are you sure?</p>
        </div>';

    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
```